# How to add a checkbox to the image in ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Please see the code below that adds images from local folder to a ListView:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_of_slides; i++) //populate the thumbnail list
{
    var fileName = @dir + (i+1) + ".png";
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName));  
    Image image = new Image() { Source = bitmap };
    image.Width = 140; 

    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();

    Thumbnails.Items.Add(image);

    //Thumbnails.Items.GetItemAt(i); here I want to somehow access current image and add checkbox in corner within that image
}
```

How to add a checkbox within each image, but not to be considered as an element in ListView, but rather than a sub element of each picture?

Comment: Isnt ListView.CheckBoxes what you need? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I believe it is. However, my ListView "Thumbnails" is created in XAML and apparently does not have CheckBoxes property. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Image` does not support content, you need to wrap both `Image` and `ComboBox` in some kind of container eg. `Grid`.

```
// set checkbox alignment
checkbox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
checkbox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
var grid = new Grid();
grid.Children.Add(image);
grid.Children.Add(checkbox);
```

Comment: Thanks, that totally worked. The only problem is that the checkbox is all over the image, not visually, but its "field" covers the entire image and it won't let me click the image (checkbox is checked wherever I click on image). How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

How about this [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754143(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FirstCell">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, 
      RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource FirstCell}" Width="30"/>
```